# Explain the modulus function through this problem?

Tags: logarithms, absolute-value

[image]

I have easily solved a lot of log equations which do not involve the modulus function. I know the definition of the modulus function. But, how does this function affect the solutions of a equation? The given equation is an example.Can someone explain me the approach to solving equations having modulus by using this example (detailed explanation will be appreciated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain gives $x\geq0$.

Now for $0\leq x\leq1$ we get an identity.

For $x>1$ the $|.|$ disappears and we obtain:
$$(2\sqrt{x}-1)^2=8\sqrt{x}-7,$$
which gives also $x=4$ and we get the answer:
$$[0,1]\cup\left\{4\right\}$$

Comment: So, I have to check the domain of x before solving equations with modulus, right?

Comment: @Mriganka Parasar Yes, of course, but also we need to solve it.

Comment: Did you get the identity by observation?

Comment: @Mriganka Parasar Because $|x|=x$ for $x\geq0$ and $|x|=-x$ for $x\leq0$. In our case for $0\leq x\leq1$ we obtain: $\sqrt{x}+|\sqrt{x}-1|=\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x}+1=1$.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Actually, you wrote 0 twice by mistake, so I was confused. Now, its fine.

Comment: @Mriganka Parasar It was typo. Thank you!